# Проблема при подключении библиотеки к приложению

Tags: java, android, android-sdk

Добрый день.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём может быть проблема.  При разработке приложения с использованием GridLayout я подключил к приложению библиотеку android.support.v7, чтобы этот GridLayout мог подерживаться, начиная с Android 2.3. Но почему-то не получается запустить приложение на эмуляторе, т.к. получаю следующее (часть лога):

```
09-03 09:33:02.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1234): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-03 09:33:02.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1234): Process: ru.dontsov.labs, PID: 1234
09-03 09:33:02.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1234): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to   start activity ComponentInfo{ru.dontsov.labs/ru.dontsov.labs.activities.MainActivity}:   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
 09-03 09:33:02.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1234):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
 09-03 09:33:02.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1234):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
09-03 09:33:02.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1234):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
09-03 09:33:02.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1234):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
09-03 09:33:02.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1234):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-03 09:33:02.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1234):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
09-03 09:33:02.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1234):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
09-03 09:33:02.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1234):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-03 09:33:02.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1234):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-03 09:33:02.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1234):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
09-03 09:33:02.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1234):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
09-03 09:33:02.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1234):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

В xml activity_main (часть):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#0099cc"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:columnCount="4"
    app:orientation="vertical"
    app:rowCount="7" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnOne"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        app:layout_column="0"
        app:layout_gravity="top|left"
        app:layout_row="1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/_1"
        android:onClick="buttonClick"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_button"
        android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
        android:shadowDx="0"
        android:shadowDy="0"
        android:shadowRadius="5"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="@string/_1" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnTwo"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        app:layout_column="1"
        app:layout_gravity="top|left"
        app:layout_row="1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/_2"
        android:onClick="buttonClick"
        android:text="2"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_button"
        android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
        android:shadowDx="0"
        android:shadowDy="0"
        android:shadowRadius="5"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

В чём может быть проблема? Заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: Как-то неправильно подключена библиотека, мне кажется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ тут есть: 
[решение на англо-саксонском](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9126780/how-to-make-android-gridlayout-compatible-to-older-version)

По русски:

1) Проблема в отсутствии нужного класса в библиотеках проекта.

2) Надо добавить ещё одну библиотеку так же, как и support-lib: сначала добавить в workspace "проект из существующего кода" отсюда:

> your-android-sdk\extras\android\support\v7\gridlayout

далее в свойствах вашего проекта добавить предыдущий проект как библиотеку.

3) Всё работает.

Comment: В том-то и дело, я так делал, добавил этот проект как библиотеку, но всё равно не работает.

Comment: Я брал приведённый выше код, удалял все атрибуты с namespace "app", и у меня всё запускалось. Вы уверены, что подключили обе библиотеки? В вопросе вашем явно только про одну сказано.

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь, да, проблема была в подключении библиотек.